# Flask on Heroku lots of 500 errors, runs on development machine

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I just had a quick question about running flask on Heroku. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm very new, so please forgive silly mistakes.

I'm deploying an app on Heroku using Flask. To ensure minimal mistakes in implementation, code was taken directly from https://github.com/orf/simple. I made some small adjustments when following this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python. While the program works fine when I run on the dev machine (via python simple.py), the program hits consistent internal server errors on heroku. Logs are attached.

Any thoughts?

```
2012-06-23T02:43:47+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 69a4995 by *********@gmail.com
2012-06-23T02:43:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2012-06-23T02:43:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2012-06-23T02:43:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-06-23T02:43:47+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn simple:app -b 0.0.0.0:25399 -w 3`
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:49 [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:49 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:49 [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:49 [6] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6)
2012-06-23T02:43:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:49 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.13.4
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25399 (2)
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-06-23 02:43:50 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2012-06-23T02:43:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-06-23T02:43:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-23T02:45:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=238
2012-06-23T02:45:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=238
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=238
2012-06-23T02:45:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=291
2012-06-23T02:45:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET deep-rain-4577.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=238
```

Comment: Have you tried using foreman on the local machine? It could be that your requirements.txt is incomplete.

Comment: There's a hundred of reason for you app not to work immediately on heroku. Error 500 just means there was an exception in your application. You should try to get a stacktrace to know more about the problem. Some ``logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Does your app work locally? What does your Procfile look like?

Also, it seems that Heroku acts funky when dealing with threads. It looks like your app got a SIGTERM after a few seconds. I would put in some print statements to determine the last few things the app does before it terminates.

Is this your first flask application? What is your end goal? To learn? If so, I wouldn't start with this. Try writing your first app from scratch so that you know what every single line does. I would start with the Flask tutorial:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/

and then maybe check out the following tutorial on deploying flask apps on Heroku:

http://ryaneshea.com/lightweight-python-apps-with-flask-twitter-bootstrap-and-heroku